# Android: Density specific graphic

Tags: android

I have read the docs and many other answers on SO that basically strongly recommend providing density specific graphics in the APK. A lazy(and sub-optimal) approach is to provide for example just *xx-hdpi* image and that will be scaled down by system.

Now, the reason cited for providing density specific resources is the introduction of pixelation and artifacts while even scaling down otherwise. This made me question that the alternative images that I am providing are what I manually scaled down in photoshop to match the density. If Android is ultimately complaining about scaling, is my approach of scaling down in PS inherently flawed? What is the ideal way to go about it?

Comment: "If Android is ultimately complaining about scaling, is my approach of scaling down in PS inherently flawed?" -- no. Android needs to do this scaling with minimal CPU and memory requirements. Photoshop has fewer restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the down scaling algorithm for android is optimized for speed and not for accurate scaling and hence down scaling your image is not a good option.
And it may affect your image to loose its original aspect ratio.

It is always a good option to provide images for various densities in the drawable folders.Most of the times having an hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi image works but if required create other drawable folders.

You can also use vector images which do not require including multiple images for different densities.